# Cannot open link in a new tab inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Given `src.html`:

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">StackOverflow</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and `iframe.html`

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test iframe</title>
</head>
<body>

  <iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="src.html">
  </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click StackOverflow link, it cannot open on a new tab.

---

- Removed `rel` attribute
- [Googled around this](https://www.google.com/search?q=iframe+open+link+in+new+tab)
- No console error

Answer (score 2):

according to [MDN documentation: iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), the `sandbox` attribute needs to set to `allow-popups`:

> Allows popups (such as `window.open()`, `target="_blank"`, or `showModalDialog()`). If this keyword is not used, the popup will silently fail to open.